# How To Create a Site Map For Automatically Converted images Post

Tags: php, xml, sitemap

I have a Wallpaper downloading website, thats running under CodeIgniter frame work.

Whenever I upload an image, That will automatically Create a post based on available resolution. For Example, If I upload an image with 1366x768 Resolution image, That will create some posts with 1024x728 1280x720, etc. But my site map index only main URL. I mean 1366x768 sized image.

now I want to add automatically created images post list to XML

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a sitemap.php file first with a code like below. Then rewrite the URL of sitemap.php as sitemap.xml via HTACCESS.

```
<?php header("Content-type: text/xml");?>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
   xmlns:image="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1">
   // run a foreach loop and echo the concerned urls
  <url> 
    <loc>http://example.com/sample.html</loc> // URL to your post
    <image:image>
        <image:loc>http://example.com/image.jpg</image:loc> // URL to the image with a specific resolution
    </image:image>
  </url>
  // end foreach loop here
</urlset>
```

Comment: I am a beginner for CodeIgniter and XML, Can u please tell me clearly.

Comment: Can you fetch the URL(s) of posts / images? If yes, then simply echo out the URLs in example locations and you are done